# Linked Attachments in Horde

Tags: ubuntu, email

I do have the problem, that since my update to Horde 5.1.4, I am not able to attach a file for real to the email. It only creates the link to the webmailer and puts that to the end of the mail.
In the previous versions it was possible to disable this feature while composing a mail. But for some reason I cannot find that option anywhere anymore.

Any suggestions?